# String Split C# having similar delimter

Tags: c#, string

I want to split the following string with delimiter ':'

```
string s = key1:::key2:value1:::value2;
```

so the my string would split into

```
s1 = key1:::key2
s2 = value1:::value2
```

i used delimiter ':' to split the string but it's giving me following result

```
s1 = key1
s2 = ""...etc
```

Kindly help me how to split the above string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend using another delimiter instead of `:`. Why not use a special character.

Comment: You could start by replacing `:::` by something else e.g.: `@@@` and then use the split on `:`

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = "key1:::key2:value1:::value2";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(s, "(?<!:):(?!:)");
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me as the values are still within their key/value pairs as required by the OP

Answer (score 1):

```
Firstly replace ":::" with "$"

s.replace(":::",$).Split(':')

s1 = key1$key2
s2 = value1$value2 


now replace "$" with ":::"

s1 = key1:::key2
s2 = value1:::value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
Regex.Split("key1:::key2:value1:::value2", "(?<!:):(?!:)");
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iO6iZ9/4)

Comment: And how is your regex demo different with Ulugbek Umirov?

Comment: No I don't see Ulugbek demo i was busy to prepare my demo and post answer without seen.If any one have issue, i can delete my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
string s = "key1:::key2:value1:::value2";
string[] spl = s.replace(":::","|").split(':');
spl[0] = spl[0].replace("|",":::");
spl[1] = spl[1].replace("|",":::");
```